# drupal 7 - drupal_goto arguments

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I made a view with views module: "exampleview"

View needs an argument: "myarg"

I can load my page at "exampleview/myarg" and at "exampleview".

When I call drupal_goto('exampleview/myarg'); the destination is only "exampleview".

Same result with:

$arr = array('exampleview','myarg');
drupal_goto($arr);

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is from [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)

> Usually the redirected URL is constructed from this function's input parameters. However you may override that behavior by setting a destination in either the $_REQUEST-array (i.e. by using the query string of an URI) This is used to direct the user back to the proper page after completing a form. For example, after editing a post on the 'admin/content'-page or after having logged on using the 'user login'-block in a sidebar. The function drupal_get_destination() can be used to help set the destination URL.

It seems like your destination parameter is set so you have to clear destination parameter or use [header function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)